Why is $\frac1{225}\sum_{r=0}^{25} (4r+1)\binom{25}r$ equal to $51$ and not $47$?
What is wrong in my approach in constructing the general term? I was attempting this question

If $C(r)\equiv{}^{25}C_r=\dbinom{25}r$ and
$$C(0) + 5 C(1) + 9 C(2) + \ldots + 101 C(25) = 225k$$
then $k$ is equal to ?

and I wrote the general term as $$(1 + 4(r-1))\cdot25C(r-1) ,  1\leq r\leq 26$$
but in the solution the general term was written as $$(4r + 1)\cdot25C(r) ,  0\leq r\leq 25$$
Initially I had the thought that since both the terms will result in the same expansion i would get the same answer but I got the answer as 47 when the answer was 51.
So please help me understand what am i doing wrong here ?
edit:
$${}^nC_r = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$
In order to solve the question, I adopted the following approach,
$$(1 + 4(r-1))\cdot25C(r-1) = -3\cdot25C(r-1) + 4\cdot r\cdot25C(r-1) , 1\leq r\leq 26$$
$$= -3\cdot25C(r-1) + 4\cdot25\cdot24C(r-2) , 1\leq r\leq 26$$
$$= -3\cdot 2^{25} + 4\cdot25\cdot2^{24} = 50\cdot2^{25} - 3\cdot2^{25} = k\cdot2^{25}$$
$$ k = 47 $$
but the answer should be 51 using the general term given in the solution.

Please share your steps

Please, use LaTeX in order to improve readability.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

$Cr \equiv 25 Cr$, then $Cr \equiv 0$.

@user170231 yes, that is what i wish to compute but am unable to understand what i am doing wrong

I've updated your question per that clarification. Your sequence function in terms of $r-1$ is the same as the proposed function in terms of $r$, it's just a question of shifting the index and domain of $r$ by one unit.

Can you please tell if the functions are same then why my answer is different from the one in the solution

This can be written as $$\sum_{k=0}^{25} (4k+1)\binom{25}k$$

Aah! Thank you very much I understand now. Thank you for bearing with me.

$$(r-1)\cdot{^{25}C_{r-1}} = \frac{(r-1)\cdot25!}{(r-1)!(26-r)!} = \frac{25\cdot24!}{(r-2)!(26-r)!} = 25\cdot{^{24}C_{r-2}}$$
The LHS requires $(r-1)$, so don't expand $1+(r-1)4$ to $-3+4r$. Also beware of the case $r=1$.

Thank you very much. I understand now and arrived at the correct answer using your insight.

Your general term is $(4(r-1)+1)C(r-1)$ where $0\leq r-1\leq 25$ and the given general term is $(4r+1)C(r)$ where $0\leq r\leq 25$, so they are the same thing, just shifted by $1$.
As for the answer, you missed the $r=1$ case when going from $r\cdot{}^{25}C_{r-1}$ to $25\cdot{}^{24}C_{r-2}$ you made a mistake. It should be
$$r\cdot{}^{25}C_{r-1}=(r-1)\cdot{}^{25}C_{r-1}+{}^{25}C_{r-1}=25\cdot{}^{24}C_{r-2}+{}^{25}C_{r-1}$$
That will give you the missing $4$.
Hope this helps. :)
